# Custom drawing on UIView gets pixelated when zooming in

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm having some issues while trying to draw lines smoothly on touches moved when my `UIView` is zoomed in. The thing is that lines start to look very pixelated upon certain zoom level. 
My view hierarchy is really simple as of now, since this is more like a proof of concept. I have a `UIScrollView`, my `UIView` as a child and also it is set as the zoom view.

My `drawRect:` implementation looks like this:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[self.layer renderInContext:context];

CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(_previousPoint1, _previousPoint2);
CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(_currentPoint, _previousPoint1);

CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, _previousPoint1.x, _previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Dumping the contents of the layer into the context is an important part since I'm only refreshing the bounding box enclosing the path formed by the last three touched points (`_previousPoint1`, `_previousPoint2` and `_currentPoint`).
That operation is actually done on `touchesMoved` method and the function that handles it is the following:

```
- (void)calculateMinImageArea:(CGPoint)pp1 :(CGPoint)pp2 :(CGPoint)cp
{
    // calculate mid point
    CGPoint mid1    = midPoint(pp1, pp2);
    CGPoint mid2    = midPoint(cp, pp1);

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, pp1.x, pp1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
    CGRect bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path);
    CGPathRelease(path);

    CGRect drawBox = [self extendedRect:bounds];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawBox.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:drawBox];
}
```

I was able to find a workaround using `CAShapeLayers` to draw the paths. However, the low performance wasn't acceptable.

I would really appreciate if someone can point me to the right approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self setContentScaleFactor:scale];
```

use this in `scrollViewDidEndZooming:` delegate method

Hope this help's you

Comment: This definitely seems to be the way to go, however I ran into some issues:

1. When I end zooming in, only the path formed by the last three touched points gets drawn. The rest is lost, like the contents of the layer are not getting dumped into the current graphics context
2. If I draw with the view zoomed in, the screen doesn't refresh anymore on touches moved and I can only see what I draw on touches ended (the path doesn't look pixelated, so that's good stuff!)

Any idea what may be causing this effect?

Comment: What is your maximum zoomScale?

Comment: It is 5 and the minimum, in case it matters, is 0.5

Comment: then do one thing if the scale>2.0 set [self setContentScaleFactor:2.0] it is not 100% but some what better.

Comment: Same thing happens. I'm trying to figure out if there's something wrong with my drawing routine.